# Display 'build date' in footer

Tags: .net, build, version

I am not sure if this is allowed as I don't have any code to show because I do not have a clue how to do this.  I would like to display the latest build date in the footer along side the version number.  I am building a test application in .net 6 with Visual Studio. Any advice would be very much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an easy answer with .NET 6. You can either just use the built-in auto-incrementor to display an increasing version number, try to embed the date in your version number, or get into a much more complex way of customizing the assembly information and retrieving it.

For the embedded date in your version, refer to this:
https://sachabarbs.wordpress.com/2020/02/23/net-core-standard-auto-incrementing-versioning/

For the more complex approach to customizing the assembly information:
https://www.meziantou.net/getting-the-date-of-build-of-a-dotnet-assembly-at-runtime.htm

Comment: Thank you Justin, I did try the Meziantou method but being a complete newbie I struggled with what it all meant.  I will have another go and see if I can get it to work. Appreciate your help!